# How can I write a regex pattern for this sentence inside of a longer paragraph?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out the best way to match a pattern that I'm looking for in some documents. The main line that I am interested in is the line:

**"FOR PURPOSES OF WRITING THIS LOAN DOCUMENT, DRSI IS THE GRANTEE OF WRIT"**

While in some documents it appears in complete bold face, it does not necessarily have to, so I am not relying on that attribute of the text. However, it certainly comes in a separate paragraph, with the title "DSRI" and the paragraph's content is essentially always the same.

Does anyone have a good regex for the single sentence that I need to find?

> WORDS USED OFTEN IN THIS DOCUMENT 
> Words used in multiple sections
> of this document are defined below. Other words are defined in
> Sections 1, 2, 3, 4. Certain rules about the usage of words used in
> this document are also provided in Section 20. 
>  
> (A)
> "Loan Document" means this instrument, which is dated August 1, 2011.
> The term "Loan Document" includes any Addendums recorded with this
> Loan Document 
> (B) "Borrower" means JOHN A.
> SMITH
>  who sometimes will be called "Borrower"
> and sometimes simply "I" or "me". "Borrower" is granting a loan under
> this Loan Document. "Borrower" is not necessarily the same as the
> Person or Persons who signed the Document. The obligations of
> Borrowers who did not sign the Document are explained further in
> Section 23. 
> ###POSSIBLE NEW PAGE######
>
> (C) "DRSI" is Document Reading services, INC. DRSI
> is a separate corporation that is acting solely as nominee for Lender
> and Lender's successors and assigns. DRSI is organized and existing
> under the laws of California, and has an address and telephone number
> of P.O. Box 1111, Oakland, CA 1111-1111, tel(111) 111-DRSI. FOR
> PURPOSES OF WRITING THIS LOAN DOCUMENT, DRSI IS THE GRANTEE OF WRIT.
>
> (D) "Lender" means LendersCorp, Inc. 
>  
> Lender is a
> corporation or association which exists under the laws of Illinois
>
> Lender's address is 1111 Maine St, Maine City, IL 11111-1111
>
> Except as provided in Sections 2 and 10, the term "Lender" may include
> any Person who takes ownership of this Loan and this Loan Document.
>
> (E) "Loan" means the loan signed by John A. SMITH 
>
>  
>  and dated August 1, 2011         .This Loan shows that its
> signer or signers owe Lender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
FOR PURPOSES.*?DRSI.*?\.
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/1IJaO5wnAb30Fy).

The regex `.*?` means "as little as possible" and `\.` means a literal dot.

---

To match the whole paragraph:

```
(?s)(?<=\([A-Z]\)\s)"DRSI".*?(?=\s*(\([A-Z]\)|$))
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/DaNO9kvdNZ4R2S).

Note: Depending on whether your tool/language support inline flags, `(?s)`, which is the “dot matches newline” flag, may have to be removed and the “m” flag applied (typically as an extra parameter to the function call).

Comment: Quick follow up—how would you do a regex on just the entire "DRSI" paragraph—assuming that the letter (C) can change from document to document?

Comment: Bonus answer added.